# Efficient/fast Mahalanobis distance computation

Tags: computational-statistics, distance

Suppose I have $n$ data points $x_1,\dots,x_n$, each of which is $p$-dimensional. Let $\Sigma$ be the (non-singular) population covariance of these samples. With respect to $\Sigma$, what is the most efficient way known to compute the vector of squared Mahalanobis distances (from $\vec 0$) of the n data points.

That is we would like to compute the vector $(x_1^T\Sigma^{-1}x_1,\dots,x_n^T\Sigma^{-1}x_n)$.

Computing the inverse $\Sigma^{-1}$ seems to be quite slow for large matrices. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Can you give reference for this information please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Let $x$ be one of your data points.
2. Compute the [Cholesky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) decomposition $\Sigma=LL^\top$.
3. Define $y=L^{-1}x$.
4. Compute $y$ by [forward-substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_substitution) in $Ly=x$.
5. The Mahalanobis distance to the origin is the squared euclidean norm of $y$:

$$
\begin{align}
x^\top\Sigma^{-1}x &= x^\top(LL^\top)^{-1}x \\
&= x^\top(L^\top)^{-1}L^{-1}x \\
&= x^\top(L^{-1})^\top L^{-1}x \\
&= (L^{-1}x)^\top(L^{-1}x) \\
&= \|y\|^2.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I had an issue with the accuracy of this proposed algorithm and created a new question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147654/cholesky-factorization-and-forward-substitution-less-accurate-than-inversion

Comment: Without wanting to take away anything from how insight full this answer is (I up-voted earlier); especially because the OP (@Lepidopteris) uses MATLAB I would argue that for *implementation purposes *only* one should use `x'* Sigma \ x` where effectively `Sigma \ x` will take care of the `inv(A) * x` (please never use this later command).

Comment: Why do you say for implementation purposes one should use x'* Sigma \ x? Why is chol not a good option in MATLAB?

Comment: @Lepidopterist: I have answered this comment in the comments of the new question.